# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: USER)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, mailer, mailjet

I just built a really simple mailer using Rails 6 and when i deployed to production the error popped up, saying i was missing the User param is missing, fyi, is just a landpage with the form where you do not have to log in to send anything, you just fill it out and we get the information thru the email.
here is the form view:

```
<div class="form">
  <div class="row">
    <%= form_for :contact, url: send_contact_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Full Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email Address" %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number, placeholder: "Phone Number" %>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <%= f.text_field :partner_name, placeholder: "Partner's Full Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :partner_email, placeholder: "Partner's Email" %>
    <%= f.text_field :partner_phone, placeholder: "Partner's Phone" %>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.select(:category, categories, placeholder: "Category") %>
    <%= f.number_field :paid_amount, step: 0.01, placeholder: "Amount Paid" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.text_area :message, placeholder: "Anything you would want to say" %>
  <%= f.submit "Send Info" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

here is the controller:

```
  def create_contact
    contact = User.new(contact_params)
    if contact.save
      send_contact(contact)
      send_copy(contact)
      flash[:success] = 'Message sent successfully!'
    else
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:notice] = 'Error, try again'
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone_number, :partner_name, :partner_email, :partner_phone, :message, :amount_paid, :category)
  end

  def send_contact(contact)
    mail = Mailjet::Send.create(messages: [{
      "From"=> {
        "Email"=>"email",
        "Name"=>"name"
      },
      "To"=> {
        "Email"=>"email",
        "Name"=>"name"
      },
      "Subject"=>"subject",
      "HTMLPart"=>template(contact)
    }])
  end
```

thanks, im using pg as the db and mailjet as the mailing service

Comment: what is the actual error that appears on the logs?

Comment: FATAL -- : [dcc1dfcf-5bfb-4b59-9318-ddc30333a8e1]   
2021-09-28T17:38:18.680224+00:00 app[web.1]: [dcc1dfcf-5bfb-4b59-9318-ddc30333a8e1] ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is the following line:

```
<%= form_for :contact, url: send_contact_path do |f| %>
```

Namely the first parameter :contact. What this does is that the object you receive through the html form is `contact` instead of `user`, then in strong parameters you get the error `user` missing, because it is not there, if you would replace it with require `contact` it would also work as expected.

Here is `#form_for` api docs for reference:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for